# Use static ip for MySQL connection in Heroku app

Tags: python, mysql, laravel, heroku

I have a python script that connects to an external database and outputs the results in JSON

This external database can be only accessed by whitelisted IP's

But this script is INSIDE a Laravel project hosted in Heroku

I installed a Static IP plugin (Proximo) but i need how to setup the MySQL connection

```
  // Laravel controller retrieves data from the python script by calling it from the shell
  $dataString = shell_exec("python3 storage/app/path/to/python_script.py");
  $data = JsonHelper::loadFromString($dataString);
```

Python script:

```
 def getData()
    with open(path + '/query.txt', 'r') as f:
        queryString = f.read()
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="<database host>",
        user="<user>",
        password="<password>",
        database = '<database name>'
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(queryString)
    return mycursor.toList()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  result = data()
  print(json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Nothing should change in your python script. Install the proximo wrapper in your project. Refer to the [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo#installing-the-proximo-wrapper). Then try running `shell_exec("bin/proximo python3 storage/app/path/to/python_script.py");`

Comment: Executing `bin/proximo python3 storage/app/path/to/python_script.py` from heroku bash returns this:

`Proxying traffic bound for 0.0.0.0/0 via Proximo host <proximo ip>:1080 `

After 1-2 minutes, the script stops without printing nothing

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [fixie-wrench](https://github.com/usefixie/fixie-wrench), a library which does port forwarding over a SOCKS5 proxy. This allows your application to connect to MySQL as if it were running on a local port.

Fixie-wrench was developed and open sourced by Fixie, a provider of a static IP addon for Heroku, but the library works with any SOCKS5 proxy including those provided by Proximo.

After installing `fixie-wrench` you can can run it by executing `./bin/fixie-wrench $localPort:$remoteHost:$remotePort`. For example, to proxy port 3306 from mysql.example.com to port 13306 on your local machine: `./bin/fixie-wrench 13306:mysql.example.com:3306`.